# generate random GUID ....i want save my file with new guid.tostring

Tags: c#

how to generate 6 number  as => 2 numbers is Const + and 4 numbers is random  for Example => 228796 or 225564

Comment: Generate 4 random numbers and append to the constant numbers...?

Comment: Which one? GUID or your custom thing? Your custom thing is **not** a GUID.

Comment: Have you even tried *anything*? Your question was answered many times before, however not in the exact same way. We´re not willing to do what you´re supposed to do - *thinking*.

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: A 'GUID' is a well-defined thing and what you want to create is not a GUID.

Comment: You mean "digits" not numbers. Big difference.

Comment: @JustCarty :yes or invers

Comment: @EvanHuang :   public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = ", ,PageImage")]Page page, HttpPostedFileBase imgUp)
        {
                           if (imgUp != null)
                {
                    page.PageImage = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + Path.GetExtension(imgUp.FileName);
                    imgUp.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/pageImages/" + page.PageImage));
               ...........................======>>>>>>> here my Image Save with GUID name to folder......i want my image not at all was guid i want have 2 const number at first

Comment: So, you **don't want a GUID** ... Keep in mind, that if you proceed the way you intend to, you have no guarantee your filenames will be unique. You will need to check that or live in fear of collisions. Also mind that with 4 digits, you can only store 9999 different files of the same type (file extension) in that folder. With increasing probability of collision the more files are already there.

Answer (score 6):

First what you intend to be a `GUID` isn´t a `GUID`, which is a reversed thing for something like this: `"353e1ff6-0493-48f6-953e-15ec5e383034"`. As of [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.guid(v=vs.110).aspx):

> A GUID is a 128-bit integer (16 bytes) that can be used across all computers and networks wherever a unique identifier is required.

Apart from this you can easily create a randomizer that creates numbers between zero and 9999 and use those numbers as your second part:

```
string constPart = "22";
Random r = new Random();
string myNumber = constPart + r.Next(0, 10000);
```

You can - even simpler - also use a randomizer for ranges between 220000 and 229999 as follows:

```
Random r = new Random();
string myNumber = r.Next(220000, 230000).ToString();
```

Be aware that those numbers aren´t neccessarily unique. That means the more numbers you create, the more does the probability of duplicates increase.

Comment: only format random part to have 4 digits (format 0000)

Comment: "why not just generate a number from 220000-229999?" - BugFinder

Comment: @BugFinder Ohh, nice idea... updated :)

Comment: BugFinder's idea. I just cited his comment to another answer :) +1 for the GUID-Part of this answer, btw.

Comment: thanks All....oo is really simply ,,,thanks...it isnt relation to guid

Comment: thanks  @HimBromBeere

Answer (score 0):

You can simply just use the Random Class.
Make a new Instance of it and use the Next method which has parameters for minimum, maximum.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int const1 = 1;
        int const2 = 2;

        Random rng = new Random();

        string id = $"{const1}{const2}";

        for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            id += $"{rng.Next(0, 10)}";
        }

        Console.WriteLine(id);
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: why not just generate a number from 220000-229999?

Comment: ... which still wouldn't have anything to do with a GUID.